# Subtracting from the length of an array

Tags: javascript, string-length

Need clarification on the below. Answer is "dog" and would like to know why.

Example:

```
var animals = ["parrot", "cat", "dog"];

console.log(animals[animals.length - 1]);
```

Console = "dog".

Comment: Arrays in javascript are 0-indexed. So the last element is at index `length - 1` as the first element is at `1 - 1`. The `i-th` element is indexed at `i - 1`.

Comment: The length of the array is 3, the indexes are 0, 1, and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Animal length = 3 as contains 3 elements.
Animals.length - 1 = 2nd element(3-1). Ryt?

If you see in Animal at index 2, the value is dog since array start at 0 index.

```
 Animal[0] = parrot
 Animal[1]=cat 
 Animal[2]=dog
```

Answer (score 0):

`array[index]` is a way to access the element of the array .In your case `animals` in an array &  `animal.length-1` will be a number.The `index` starts from 0 so  `animal.length-1` will point to the element with index 2. In this array `dog` occupying the second index, so it is consoling dog

```js
var animals = ["parrot", "cat", "dog"];
console.log(animals.length) // 3
var _index = animals.length - 1 // 2
console.log(animals[_index]) // will print element in the index 2
```